# I could not find the library in dll

Tags: c#, dll

I am trying to seperate the code as main and dll files but when I try writing the code I got some errors.Actually I am not good at adding dll.I am trying to learn and trying to be worked it for windows form.

EDIT:
Problem is solved with Install-Package System.Drawing.Common
when I added this package I solved the problem with adding using.System.Drawing to the code.

This is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace gdll
{
   public class Class1
   {
       private Bitmap DoGray(Bitmap bmp)
       {
           for (int i = 0; i < bmp.Height - 1; i++)
           {
               for (int j = 0; j < bmp.Width - 1; j++)
               {
                   int value = (bmp.GetPixel(j, i).R + bmp.GetPixel(j, i).G + bmp.GetPixel(j, i).B) / 3;
                   Color clr;
                   clr = Color.FromArgb(value, value, value);
                   bmp.SetPixel(j, i, clr);
               }
           }
           return bmp;
       }
   }

}
```

This is the error:

```
CS1069  The type name 'Bitmap' could not be found in the namespace 'System.Drawing'. This type has been forwarded to assembly 'System.Drawing.Common, Version=4.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' Consider adding a reference to that assembly.
```

Comment: your `DoGrey`-method should be **within** your `Class1`, not besides it.

Comment: Your method needs to go in the class, for one.

Comment: Thank you for your answers I implemented that you said now and I am gonna edit the code here but I am still getting the first error(CS1069).What can I do for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You placed the function inside the namespace and not inside the class.

Comment: I had tried to add System.Drawing.Common before writing here and also had tried to add file with Nuget but it did not work.May be I made a mistake with this.

Answer (score 0):

The errors tell you what's wrong and how to fix it.

For this error:

```
CS1069  The type name 'Bitmap' could not be found in the namespace 'System.Drawing'. This type has been forwarded to assembly 'System.Drawing.Common, Version=4.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' Consider adding a reference to that assembly.
```

It just means that you need to add a `using` to the relevant library (dll). So:

```
using System.Drawing.Common;
```

Whereas this error:

```
CS0116  A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods.
```

Tells you you've put your function directly into a namespace - which isn't where it should be, it should be in a class. So your code becomes:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Common;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace gdll
{
   public class Class1
   {

   }
   private Bitmap DoGray(Bitmap bmp)
   {
       for (int i = 0; i < bmp.Height - 1; i++)
       {
           for (int j = 0; j < bmp.Width - 1; j++)
           {
               int value = (bmp.GetPixel(j, i).R + bmp.GetPixel(j, i).G + bmp.GetPixel(j, i).B) / 3;
               Color clr;
               clr = Color.FromArgb(value, value, value);
               bmp.SetPixel(j, i, clr);
           }
       }
       return bmp;
   }
}
```